# Dynamically add page block on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, force

How to add Dynamically page block on button click.?
pleas can any one help me.

thanks In Advance.

Comment: Parth you can do one thing create pageblock with some id, and you can set visibilty off by default, using rendered = false. than on onclick you can set rendered = true.

Comment: Can you please give me example of that

Comment: ok, have you use rerender functionality ..... ?

Comment: Please try example which i mentioned below...

Comment: Out of curiosity, have  you already tried the Visualforce workbook or trailhead learning exercises ? That would be a good start if you are new to visualforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apex:repeat with a list to generate as many Page Blocks as you like.
The code below will display a button called "Add Section". One new page block will be added every time you click on the button.
Hope this helps.

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">

    <apex:form>

        <apex:commandButton value="Add Section" reRender="sectionsPanel" action="{!addSection}" />

        <apex:outputPanel id="sectionsPanel">
            <apex:repeat value="{!lstSections}" var="section">

                <apex:pageBlock title="PageBlock">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="PageBlockSection">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>Do Something Here</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>

            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class TestController {
    public List<String> lstSections { get; set; }

    public TestController(){
        lstSections = new List<String>();
    }

    public PageReference addSection() {

        lstSections.add('dummy');

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example helps you

```
 <apex:page controller="TestMyPage" >
  <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock id="block">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 1" rendered="{!showSection1}"/>                                        
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 2" rendered="{!showSection2}"/>   
         </apex:pageBlock>

              <apex:commandButton action="{!method1}" value="Show/Hide Section1" reRender="block"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!method2}" value="Show/Hide Section2"  reRender="block"/>
   </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

controller

```
public with sharing class TestMyPage{
     public Boolean showSection1{get;set;}
     public Boolean showSection2{get;set;}            

        public TestMyPage (){
             showSection1= true;
             showSection2= true;
        }

    public void method2(){
         if(showSection2== true){
             showSection2= false;
         }else{
             showSection2= true;
         }      
    }

    public void method1() {
         if(showSection1== true){
             showSection1= false;
         }else{
             showSection1= true;
         }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Dynamic Visualforce Components to create VF components dynamically on runtime. For example, to create a table:

```
Component.Apex.PageBlockTable
```

See this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097KXIAY).